# Aliasing site root to subdirectory

Tags: apache-2.4

I have a website served via Apache and I'd like to rework the directory structure a bit.
What I have right now is like:

```
/var
    /www
        /html
             index.html
             ...files for root...
             /sub-directory1
                       index.html
             /sub-directory2
                       index.html
```

I'd like to move to the following structure while keeping the content of `/main` as the root of my site:

```
/var
    /www
        /html
             /main
                       index.html
                       ...files for root...
             /sub-directory1
                       index.html
             /sub-directory2
                       index.html
```

---

What I've came up with seems kinda wonky to me, so I'd like more experienced opinions:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  ServerName X.Y.Z

  Alias "/" "/var/www/html/main"
</VirtualHost>
```

But that means that `/main` can also be viewed while not on `/`...

Another option is to use the rewrite-rule:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  ServerName X.Y.Z

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^/|(/main)$ /main/ [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Any input on the matter is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do everything with **mod_rewrite**. The exact conditions depend on the effect you want to achieve. I assume you want:

1. If a directory `sub-directory` exists in the document root, you want to serve all URLs starting with `http://example.com/sub-directory` from that directory.
2. Otherwise you want to serve the contents from the `main` directory, i.e. all regular files in `/var/www/html` will be ignored.
3. URLs starting with `http://example.com/main` will give a `404` error.

The aforementioned conditions can be met with the following rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Empty condition, we just want to capture the first path component.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}     ^(/[^/]*)
# The empty path '/' and those starting with '/main'
RewriteCond %1                 ^/(main)?$ [OR]
# together with every path, whose first component is not a directory
# (e.g. '/index.html', '/favicon.ico')
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1 !-d

# will be prepended with '/main'.
RewriteRule ^ /main%{REQUEST_URI}
# For 'http://example.com/main' it means that the server will look for
# '/var/www/html/main/main' and return a 404 error.
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that soon but it seems like a good way to do it